# how to access a file sent with phonegap filetransfer with wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, cordova, file-transfer

im trying to post files via phonegap filetransfer.upload to a wcf rest service. when i send a file to the service i manage to upload all of it, but then my log says that the HttpContext is not supported. i tried allowing asp compatibility requirements, but to no avail, and i found no equivalent with the webOperationContext. i would appreciate any help given, im stuck. here is the relevant code:
interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "putFile",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
Method = "POST") ]
     bool putFile();
}
```

implementation:

```
   public bool putFile()
        {
            try
            {
                var request = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
                String driverId = request.Headers["driverId"];
                HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];

                String fileName = file.FileName;
                int _driverId = Int32.Parse(driverId);
                String fileURI = makeLocalPath(file.ContentType, fileName,driverId);

                if (file != null)
                {
                    Entities db = new Entities();

                    var uri = db.dt_media_uri.Where(p => p.driver_id == _driverId && p.uri_value.Equals(fileName));


                    using (Stream inputStream = file.InputStream)
                    {


                        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileURI, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
                        if (fileStream == null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                            }
                            catch { return false; }
                            try
                            {
                                foreach (var v in uri)
                                {
                                    v.validated = true;
                                }
                            }

                            catch { EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "unable to validate uri for driverID: " + driverId); }
                            try
                            {
                                db.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            catch { return false; }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;

            }
            catch(Exception e) { EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "unable process filename\n"+e.ToString()); return false; }
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString=*non relevant*"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

  </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment> 
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="NewStandardEndpoint0" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="PullOverWcf.Service1">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="crossDomain" name="REST" contract="PullOverWcf.IService1" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="crossDomain" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="21000000"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>

      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, driverID" />

      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <!--authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication-->
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and this is from the client:

```
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {
    driverId : self.driverId
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(options));
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(path, encodeURI(self.serverPath + "/putFile"), fileSuccess,
        fileFail, options);
```

Comment: eventually, [MultipartParser.cs](http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MultipartParser.cs) did the trick.